# How to install Magento CE 2 to specific MySQL version

Tags: magento2, database, magento-ce

this is my first post, maybe it's so basic question.

I have a problem when installing magento CE 2, I got notice "only support MySQL version 5.6.0 or later". But I have 2 versions MySQL installed in my computer, 5.0 and 5.7.11. How do I choose a specific MySQL version so I can install magento correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Check your PHP configuration by calling `phpinfo();` in a PHP file or `php -i` on the command line.

The MySQL version you see in your PHP configuration is used for the setup so you need to adjust it there.